# Rangy loses caret position on backspace in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, dom, contenteditable, rangy

I have researched all the Rangy Q&As for days but could not adapt anything to this case.

I have the following contenteditable

```
<div id="area" style="width:100%;height:2em;" 
contentEditable="true";
onkeyup="formatText();"
></div>
```

calling a function that every time the user types something, it parses the content and formats specific tokens.

```
 function formatText() {

    var el = document.getElementById('area');
    var savedSel = saveSelection(el); // calls Rangy function

    var tokenColor;

        // removes html tags before passing the expression to the parser
    var userInput = document.getElementById('area').innerHTML.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g,"").replace(/&amp;/g, "").replace(/&gt;/g, ">").replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/<span[^>]*>+<\/span>/, "");


    var i, newHTML=[];

    tokenType=[]; // [NUMBER,+,(,NUMBER,..]
    tokenArray=[]; // [3,+,(5,...]

    var resultOutput =  parse(userInput); // parser also fills tokenType and tokenArray

    for (i=0; i<tokenArray.length-1; i++){

        newHTML += "<span style='color: " + tokenColor + " '>" +  tokenArray[i] + "</span>";

         } // newHTML looks like <span style='color: red'>3</span><span style='color: black'>+</span> etc.


    el.innerHTML = newHTML; // replaces content of <div> with formatted text    

    restoreSelection(el, savedSel);  // calls Rangy function to restore cursor position
}
```

I use the following Rangy based functions presented by the author in other posts on this forum:

```
    function saveSelection(containerEl) {
    var charIndex = 0, start = 0, end = 0, foundStart = false, stop = {};
    var sel = rangy.getSelection(), range;

    function traverseTextNodes(node, range) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            if (!foundStart && node == range.startContainer) {
                start = charIndex + range.startOffset;
                foundStart = true;
            }

            if (foundStart && node == range.endContainer) {
                end = charIndex + range.endOffset;
                throw stop;
            }
            charIndex += node.length;


        }  else {
            for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                traverseTextNodes(node.childNodes[i], range);
            }   
        }
    }

    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        try {
            traverseTextNodes(containerEl, sel.getRangeAt(0));
        } catch (ex) {
            if (ex != stop) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}



function restoreSelection(containerEl, savedSel) {
    var charIndex = 0, range = rangy.createRange(), foundStart = false, stop = {};
    range.collapseToPoint(containerEl, 0);

    function traverseTextNodes(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
            if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
                range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
                foundStart = true;
            }
            if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
                range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
                throw stop;
            }
            charIndex = nextCharIndex;
        }   

        else {
            for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
                traverseTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        traverseTextNodes(containerEl);
    } catch (ex) {
        if (ex == stop) {
            rangy.getSelection().setSingleRange(range);   
        } else {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly until I try to delete a character. At that point, the cursor jumps at the beginning of the div.

Any idea of why this could happen?

Many thanks.

Comment: You destroy and replace the entire contents of the div with innerHTML, so the nodes that were selected no longer exist. Instead of using innerHTML, you should manually remove nodes that you don't want, leaving the others intact.

Comment: @GGG: The second block of code does a character index-based save and restore of the selection, so as long as the visible text remains unchanged after the `innerHTML` replacement, it should work.

Comment: @TimDown I see what you mean now, I just skimmed over that part before. I still have my doubts about this working. Some of the regexes  look like they'd create broken markup. `'<span></span>'.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/, '') // "</span>"`

Comment: @GGG: I used the following link for REGEX http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/all_about_html_tags.htm. COuld you please suggest a better option to remove all span tags without their content? This should also remove empty spans like <span></span> and spans with hidden characters. Probably on pressing delete some strange span is created if javascript replace DEL with a special hidden character?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem with Tim Down's help (thanks Tim!).

He has recently added the new TextRange module to Rangy and it works perfectly. The module has a selection save/restore based on character index within the visible text on a page and is therefore immune to innerHTML changes. You can find the demo here:

http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html

Documentation (preliminary): http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule

So basically the code shall be:

```
    document.getElementById("area").onkeyup = function() {
    var sel = rangy.getSelection();
    var savedSel = sel.saveCharacterRanges(this);    

    var userInput = this.textContent || this.innerText;

    var userInputLength = userInput.length;  
    var newHTML = [];

    for (var i=0; i<userInputLength; i++) {
        newHTML[i] = "<span style='color: red'>" + userInput.charAt(i)  + "</span>";  
    }

    this.innerHTML =  newHTML.join("");

    sel.restoreCharacterRanges(this, savedSel);
};
​
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though it could work. The solution may be as simple as calling the `focus()` method of the contenteditable `<div>` before restoring the selection.

Comment: Hi Tim, as per your suggestion I added the following: 
 $('#area').focus(); 
 
 restoreSelection(el, savedSel);
}                                                                            but still does nott work on pressing delete. It deletes the last character and jumps at the beginning of the div. It works perfectly as you type though so it is strange. it seems that on delete an empty <span></span> block is generated and the first Range.StartContainer.nodeName="SPAN".COuld this be the reason?

Comment: UPDATE: I think this is related to another issue: when pressing SHIFT + right arrow, it correctly highlights the characters going forward. When you try to use the left arrow, it highlights one character, then moves the cursor left, then highlights another character and so forth.I think there is some logic that does not like backwards actions like delete or highlighting backward. Thanks.